# How to go about using ownership of an NFT to allow access to a website?

Tags: web3js

So I am wondering if there is a way to use ownership of an NFT to allow access to a website? I am not sure about how to go about this but I am very interested. Any info or resources would be appreciated.

My idea is that (I own NFT X, I can now access this website through use of metamask or something).

Answer (score 2):

That's quite possible.

The website should have some way to access blockchain data. Either through the client's browser wallet (for example Metamask) or through a separate backend connection (probably through a service provider, such as Alchemy).

Once the connection is established, the website queries the specific NFT contract about who owns certain NFT. If the owner is the same address as which is connected to the website (through browser wallet), then the user is allowed to the website.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. How would I go about getting the website to query the specific NFT contract? In my head I would just make a manual list of them and then check the values against each other? Maybe there is a safer better way to do this?

Comment: That's the most straightforward way: query the contracts directly for the right data. Since the users need browser wallet anyway, you can just use that connection