# Is a nft gated website secured?

Tags: web3js, nft

I am currently following tutorials like [this one](https://portal.thirdweb.com/guides/nft-gated-website) where we learn how to create a reactJS app where we check if an user has a particular NFT before giving him access to the website. (It is also explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118715/how-to-go-about-using-ownership-of-an-nft-to-allow-access-to-a-website))

But I don't understand something. With the official website of the app, I agree we won't be able to **bypass the ownership check**. But since we can't hide any code in a frontend app, is it possible that someone just downloads the source code of the frontend app, remove the ownership check and then access to the **protected part** of the website?